# Getting count of listviews after search

Tags: android

I have an activity which have 100 list.Currently I can get the count of all list. But my problem is how to get the count of list after search? For example if I searched for keyword "apple" and there is 5 list regarding that.How to get that count 5? Similar questions or code samples will be very kind full. Forgive if I asked any blunder.

Comment: Create a sublist containing only your filtered lists and then you can interate over it as you would the superlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new list that contains only the searched items. When a user search for any keyword add all items containing that keyword into a new list. And you can easily get the size of that list.